# How to use Mdbg.exe or ICorDebug to print stack traces of all running threads of a process programmatically

Tags: c#, stack-trace, mdbg

How can I use Mdbg.exe or ICorDebug to print stack traces of all running threads of a process programmatically in c#?

thanks.

Comment: just read on Internet.

Comment: That place you read on the Internet, it didn't have any examples?

Answer (score 2):

There is an example of this in the C# source for Red Flag's "Dump Stacks" functionality.
http://redflagdebugger.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution. I downloaded CLR Managed Debugger (mdbg) Sample 4.0 with source code. I changed some source code lines to use it according to my needs.